# Flaw in the logic

Tags: ios, objective-c

Multiplication functionality is not working as per the below logic.
the output I am getting after multiplication of any two numbers is 'infinite' which is part of division logic.

Please let me know where its going wrong.

Below is the code.
To read the input.

```
-(IBAction)clickDigit:(UIButton *) sender{

 digit = (int)sender.tag;
 currentnumber = currentnumber*10 + digit;
 display.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",currentnumber];
 }
```

on load initialization code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

   [super viewDidLoad];
   displayString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:40];
   currentnumber = 0;
   digit = 0;
   op = 'a';
   firstOpr = YES;
   number1 = 0;
   }
```

Multiplication Logic

```
 - (IBAction)clickMul
{
if(op != '*')
{
    if(op =='+')
    {
        [self clickPlus];
    }
    else if (op == '-')
    {
        [self clickMinus];
    }
    else if (op == '/')
    {
        [self clickDiv];
    }
}

if(firstOpr == YES)
{
    number1 = currentnumber;
    display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",number1];
    firstOpr = NO;
    digit =0;
    currentnumber = 0;
}
else
{
    number1 = number1*currentnumber;
    display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",number1];
    digit = 0;
    currentnumber = 0;
}
op = '*';

}
```

Division Logic

```
 - (IBAction)clickDiv
 {
  if(op != '/')
  {
    if(op=='+')
    {
        [self clickPlus];
    }
    else if (op == '-')
    {
        [self clickMinus];

    }
    else if (op == '*')
    {
        [self clickMul];
    }
 }

if(firstOpr == YES)
{
    number1 = currentnumber;
    display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",number1];
    firstOpr = NO;
    digit =0;
    currentnumber = 0;
}
else
{
    if (currentnumber == 0)
    {
        display.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Infinite"];
    }
    else
    {
        number1 = number1 / currentnumber;
        display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",number1];

    }
    digit = 0;
    currentnumber = 0;
}
op = '/';

}
```

Comment: Wrong Target/Action association? :)

Comment: Association is proper. Its set to - (IBAction)clickMul

Comment: put the break point in division method and check the calling hierarchy that from where it is getting called.

Comment: @Apurv thanks for the little suggestion. Actually the problem was in a different loop. the code for the same is as below in the answers point. However, I was missing the break statement and it is working fine now.